# Custom Product.tpl with declination crash when select attribute and url change Prestashop 1.7

Tags: templates, layout, product, prestashop-1.7

I have to create a custom page for only one product with declinations, so I have created "product-158.tpl" file with a new hook for a new module. (158 is the ID of the  targeted product)
The page works well when the product is not to complicated to select, but if I need declinations as color or size, the new layout is replaced by classic product.tpl version and every customed things desapeared. The problem comes when the hidden "refresh" button is trigged and the "add-to-cart-or-refresh" form is submitted. If I erase the hidden button, I can select what I need to select, the cart recognise my order, I can buy the right declination, but If I click the "continue shopping" button, the same problem is displayed.
The problem comes when url change, maybe because of the new ID of the product, I really don't know. I'm searching from two month.
Thanks a lot to who will help me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not park the base tpl, and call your hooks, and apply only changes that the product ID is 158?

Regards

Comment: Thanks you to trying to help me !
I have tried but even if I stay on the "product.tpl" and include another "product-variants.tpl" as "product-variants-something.tpl".
Every changes reload the first "product-vartiant.tpl" and broke everything. I don't know where can I make a constant "include" of a different "product-variant" template.
I think "constant link" is the real problem. Best Regards